# Call ISE-style PowerShell from console?

Tags: powershell, command-line, powershell-2.0

In PowerShell, when one uses `Out-Gridview` while running from the console in powershell.exe, it displays a new forms-style window.  When running scripts in PowerShell ISE that call things like `Write-Progress`, they render rather differently in a new window with Windows graphical elements rather than with their usual console displays.

Is it possible to call cmdlets like `Write-Progress` in the console and get them to open ISE-style displays anyway like `Out-Gridview` always does?  Ultimately, I'd like to be able to benefit from the free UI elements meant for ISE without having to go manually create form objects, etc.

Comment: What is your use case for this? Appearances only?

Comment: Intended for use within some installers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Write-Progress` adapts its output for the host it's running in. AFAICT it's not possible to change that behavior.

Comment: Is there an out-of-the-box way to run the host that ISE uses without the entirety of ISE?

Comment: The ISE *is* the host itself in that context. It can't be split from itself.